# Python Reading URL: ChunkedEncodingError

Tags: python, python-requests, chunked-encoding

I'm using the Python requests library to open URLs. The URL is to a word document. Manually on a browser, I can access the URL, which automatically leads to a download of the document. I am able to successuflly download the document.

However, using requests, I'm getting a ChunkedEncodingError.

My code:

```
import requests
url = 'https://legalref.judiciary.hk/doc/judg/word/vetted/other/ch/2008/CACC000213A_2008.doc'
res = requests.get(url) 
print(res)
```

The error:

> raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
> requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken:
> IncompleteRead(16834 bytes read, 87102 more expected)',
> IncompleteRead(16834 bytes read, 87102 more expected))

I've also tried using other libraries, like aiohttp and urllib3, but errors also arise.

Retrying the request doesn't work, as I am getting an error each time.

If someone could help, that would be great! Some other posts say it could be a server side problem. But it works fine on a browser, and more technical details are beyond me.

Answer (score 1):

This certainly is a server-side problem – it occurs even when using `wget`, though `wget` (and your browser) is smart enough to retry from the failing byte:

```
wget -vvv 'https://legalref.judiciary.hk/doc/judg/word/vetted/other/ch/2008/CACC000213A_2008.doc'
--2024-01-24 16:05:40--  https://legalref.judiciary.hk/doc/judg/word/vetted/other/ch/2008/CACC000213A_2008.doc
Resolving legalref.judiciary.hk (legalref.judiciary.hk)... 118.143.43.114
Connecting to legalref.judiciary.hk (legalref.judiciary.hk)|118.143.43.114|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 103936 (102K) [application/msword]
Saving to: ‘CACC000213A_2008.doc’

CACC000213A_2008.doc                                   14%[=================>                                                                                                       ]  15,12K  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2024-01-24 16:05:42 (31,4 MB/s) - Read error at byte 15486/103936 (Connection reset by peer). Retrying.

--2024-01-24 16:05:43--  (try: 2)  https://legalref.judiciary.hk/doc/judg/word/vetted/other/ch/2008/CACC000213A_2008.doc
Connecting to legalref.judiciary.hk (legalref.judiciary.hk)|118.143.43.114|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 206 Partial Content
Length: 103936 (102K), 88450 (86K) remaining [application/msword]
Saving to: ‘CACC000213A_2008.doc’

CACC000213A_2008.doc                                  100%[++++++++++++++++++======================================================================================================>] 101,50K  25,8KB/s    in 3,3s

2024-01-24 16:05:50 (25,8 KB/s) - ‘CACC000213A_2008.doc’ saved [103936/103936]
```

You can implement similar logic by using `requests.get(..., stream=True)`, looking at the `Content-Length` you get, and comparing it to the bytes you've managed to write; if you get an exception and you've read less than you're expecting (via `Content-Length`), try again with a `Range: bytes={start_byte}-` style header:

```
import requests


def download_with_resume(sess: requests.Session, url: str) -> bytes:
    data = b""
    expected_length = None
    for attempt in range(10):
        if len(data) == expected_length:
            break
        if len(data):
            headers = {"Range": f"bytes={len(data)}-"}
            expected_status = 206
        else:
            headers = {}
            expected_status = 200
        print(f"{url}: got {len(data)} / {expected_length} bytes...")
        resp = sess.get(url, stream=True, headers=headers)
        resp.raise_for_status()
        if resp.status_code != expected_status:
            raise ValueError(f"Unexpected status code: {resp.status_code}")
        if expected_length is None:  # Only update this on the first request
            content_length = resp.headers.get("Content-Length")
            if not content_length:
                raise ValueError("Content-Length header not found")
            expected_length = int(content_length)

        try:
            for chunk in resp.iter_content(chunk_size=8192):
                data += chunk
        except requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError:
            pass

    if len(data) != expected_length:
        raise ValueError(f"Expected {expected_length} bytes, got {len(data)}")

    return data


with requests.Session() as sess:
    data = download_with_resume(
        sess,
        url="https://legalref.judiciary.hk/doc/judg/word/vetted/other/ch/2008/CACC000213A_2008.doc",
    )
    print("=>", len(data))
```

Comment: amazing, thanks! just pasted it in and it works. other stackoverflow questions didn't show the solution, and i, as a hobbyist, would never been able to implement this myself.